# C++ Can not create instance of abstract class

Tags: c++, windows, class, compiler-construction

I have the following class:

(header)

```
struct udtMapping
{
    int ByteStart;
    int ByteCount;
    int iHPUnitID;
};

class clsMapping : public CBaseStructure
{
private:
    vector<udtMapping> m_content;

protected:

public:
    vector<udtMapping> &Content();
    void Add(int i1, int i2, int int3);
};
```

cpp file:

```
 vector<udtMapping> &clsMapping::Content()
 {
     return m_content;
 }
 void clsMapping::Add(int i1, int i2,int i3)
 {
     udtMapping n;
     n.ByteStart = i1;
     n.ByteCount = i2;
     n.iHPUnitID  = i3;
     m_content.push_back(n);    
     return;
 }
```

Now I wanted to use this class by saying

```
clsMapping nMapping;
```

But the compiler tells me "Can not create instance from abstract class".

I am not sure where I went wrong.
Thank you for the help.

Edit: On request here is the CBaseStructure

```
 class CBaseStructure 
 {
 protected:
     virtual void ProcessTxtLine(string line) = 0;
     virtual void AfterLoad();
     virtual string CompactLine(string line);
 public:
     void Load(string file);
     void Load2(string file);
     void Load3(string file);
 };
```

Comment: There is a pure virtual member function of `CBaseStructure` that `clsMapping` is not overriding. Can you show the definition of `CBaseStructure`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CBaseStructure must be an abstract class. If you want to derive from it and you want a non-abstract class then you must override each pure virtual function that CBaseStructure declares. Clearly you didn't do that.

**EDIT**

CBaseStructure has one pure virtual function `ProcessTxtLine`. Your class must override that function.

There is nothing in your code that explains why you are inheriting from CBaseStructure, what do you thing it will do for you?

Comment: Ah, great, thank you. I don't know why I added that at all. I simply removed the " : public CBaseStructure", and it worked. Thank you.

Comment: CBaseStructure places certain expectations on any class that derives from it, you didn't meet those expectations so your code didn't compile. I advise against deriving from randomly picked classes in the future. Or indeed any random code writing. It's unlikely to work.

Comment: Yes, that may be true. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your `CBaseStructure`, please note the following `protected` pure virtual function declaration:

```
virtual void ProcessTxtLine(string line) = 0;
```

Any class with a pure virtual function is an abstract class, and abstract classes cannot be instantiated (think about why: they don't have any code to implement certain functions that they claim to support).

So, abstract classes are classes that contain pure virtual functions that the base class **requires** a derived class provide implementations for.

In your case,  your `clsMapping` class **must** provide an implementation for `ProcessTxtLine`.

So what happens if you don't? Well, your derived class "inherits" a pure virtual funcition that it doesn't override, and therefore, it too, becomes an abstract class. And as we already established, abstract classes cannot be instantiated.